# Joomla 3 Module Save Event

Tags: php, events, plugins, joomla, module

I am searching for an event that is triggered after saving a specific Module, for a Plugin.

Like the `onContentAfterSave` Event for the Content Group.

Is there such an Event, or how can i trigger such an event after save?

Comment: Please try asking your question over at [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Comment: You really have to use the postSaveHook which means overriding that method of the controller. There are some plugins in the JED that make doing that easier. It really would be good for that event to be added to some other places.

Answer (score 1):

The event triggered on module save is `onExtensionAfterSave` (Joomla 3.x). You can check how the event is associated with the module save in the file "administrator/components/com_modules/models/module.php".